# Azure Free Web Site Redirecting to www and page not found

Tags: azure, web

I just successfully published my MVC web site using Visual Studio 2013 to my free azure web site: eyepaidstage.azurewebsites.net .

When the publishing was complete my browser opened and said page not found. The url eyepaidstage.azurewebsites.net had been changed/redirected to www.eyepaidstage.azurewebsites.net .

I tested the http://eyepaidstage.azurewebsites.net and https://eyepaidstage.azurewebsites.net using IE, Chrome, and Firefox on my desktop (ISP is version) and android mobile (ATT).

Ping and NSlookup are resolving properly:

```
C:\Users\MSIH>ping eyepaidstage.azurewebsites.net

Pinging waws-prod-blu-001.cloudapp.net [168.62.48.183] with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 168.62.48.183:
    Packets: Sent = 2, Received = 0, Lost = 2 (100% loss),
Control-C
^C
C:\Users\MSIH>nslookup
Default Server:  Wireless_Broadband_Router.home
Address:  192.168.1.1

> eyepaidstage.azurewebsites.net
Server:  Wireless_Broadband_Router.home
Address:  192.168.1.1

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    waws-prod-blu-001.cloudapp.net
Address:  168.62.48.183
Aliases:  eyepaidstage.azurewebsites.net
          waws-prod-blu-001.vip.azurewebsites.windows.net

>
```

I found this in the developer tools in Chrome. It looks like azure IIS is returning status code 301!

```
Remote Address:168.62.48.183:80
Request URL:http://eyepaidstage.azurewebsites.net/
Request Method:GET
Status Code:301 Moved Permanently (from cache)
Request Headers
Provisional headers are shown
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36
X-DevTools-Emulate-Network-Conditions-Client-Id:FC8EB51B-C0D7-4998-B2A6-4493CBE72C52
Response Headers
Content-Length:0
Date:Thu, 18 Sep 2014 00:42:54 GMT
Location:http://www.eyepaidstage.azurewebsites.net:80/
Server:Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your application (eyepaidstage.azurewebsites.net) is definitely returning the 301 redirect to the location www.eyepaidstage.azurewebsites.net.  Your application must have logic to look for a www. and redirect if needed.  Or you have a URLRewrite run in your web.config file that specifies this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

As is the case most of the time it was human error. I had forgot about adding this code to the global.asax.cs file, which was redirect all request to www.

```
 protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { 
            if (!Request.Url.Host.StartsWith("www") && !Request.Url.IsLoopback)
            {
                UriBuilder builder = new UriBuilder(Request.Url);
                builder.Host = "www." + Request.Url.Host;
                Response.StatusCode = 301;
                Response.AddHeader("Location", builder.ToString());
                Response.End();
            }
        }
```